# ¿Es posible setear a null una FK antes de borrar la Primary Key para que no se borren los registros?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Me gustaría saber si es posible cambiar el valor a **NULL** para que no se pierdan X registros en Spring , cuando por ejemplo tengo algo como:

**Tabla 1** --> Pais

**Tabla 2** --> Feriado( aquí tengo FK de pais , como pais_id)

Si yo borro un ID de país(PK) en la tabla País , entonces todos los IDs relacionados en la tabla Feriado , se borrarán , lo que pregunto es, ¿es posible que no se eliminen los registros que tenga en la tabla Feriado y hay alguna manera de hacerlo en Spring?¿O lo correcto es eliminar dichos registros?

Answer (score 0):

Con la información brindado puedo ayudar diciendo:
1-) Creo que la configuración de la base de datos esta de forma CASCADE, mucho no podrás hacer con spring [Mas información sobre config de fk](https://itqna.net/questions/999/what-purpose-restrict-cascade-set-null-and-no-action-options#:%7E:text=CASCADE%3A%20Updates%20or%20deletes%20records,NO%20ACTION%3A%20Equivalent%20to%20RESTRICT.) .
2-) Siguiendo la lógica, es correcto eliminar (según mi parecer), ya que es feriado por país, y si el país no existe en tu base de datos, no debería existir su feriado correspondiente.

Comment: ¿Y si tengo varias relaciones de país con más tablas? ¿Con varias relaciones es correcto borrar físicamente también?

Comment: Depende mucho del contexto que utilices, a veces, es correcto implementar un campo mas dentro de país, que simbolice si dicho país esta enable o disable, con eso puedes manejar los registros sin la necesidad de borrar los datos.